# Using GitHub api with iOS

Tags: ios, oauth, afnetworking, restful-authentication

I registered my app on github and I have client ID and secret. I need to get the OAuth token to use it further in my app. How do I get the token?
I tried using [AFOAuth2Manager](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFOAuth2Manager) with the following code but I get an Unauthorized 401 error. Here is my code:

```
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.github.com"];
AFOAuth2Manager *OAuth2Manager =
[[AFOAuth2Manager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL
                                clientID:@"myid"
                                  secret:@"mysecret"];

[OAuth2Manager authenticateUsingOAuthWithURLString:@"/authorizations"
                                          username:@"myuser"
                                          password:@"mypass"
                                             scope:@"public_repo"
                                           success:^(AFOAuthCredential *credential) {
                                               NSLog(@"Token: %@", credential.accessToken);
                                           }
                                           failure:^(NSError *error) {
                                               NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                                           }];
```

How do I get the token?